# SetFileShortName does not reset short (8.3) name of a file

Tags: c, file, winapi, ntfs

I am trying to remove short name of a file in NTFS. I am testing it on Windows 7. I am running my process as an administrator.

Here is my code:

```
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD error = NO_ERROR;

    hFile = fh = CreateFileA(name, 
                    GENERIC_ALL,
                    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
                    NULL, 
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                    NULL);
    if(hFile == NULL || hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        if(GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
            printf("File Access Denied.\n");
        if(GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            printf("File not found.\n");
        return error;
    }
    SetLastError(NO_ERROR);

    ModifyPrivilege(SE_RESTORE_NAME, TRUE);

    SetLastError(NO_ERROR);
    SetFileShortNameW(hFile, L""); // As per MSDN, It will work only in windows 7 and above
    error = GetlastError(); // returns 1314 error  
    ModifyPrivilege(SE_RESTORE_NAME, FALSE);

    CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Code for ModifyPrivilege() is same as on MSDN:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387705(v=vs.85).aspx

I am making sure that I have SE_RESTORE_NAME privilege (using process explorer for this). Above code does not generate any error but when I look at mft record of the file in hex editor, Short file name is still there i.e. MFT record has two $30 File name attributes, one for full name and other for short name.

I want to know if my code is wrong or some thing else that I have to do? Why does not SetFileShortNameEx function does not any effect in this case?

Comment: Is it possible the file system has cached the change and not updated the MFT record yet on disk when you look at it in the hex editor? What do you get in `WIN32_FIND_DATA::cAlternateFileName` if you call `FindFirstFile` after the call to `SetFileShortName`?

Comment: You are correct. Alternate name is still the same in ( WIN32_FIND_DATA::cAlternateFileName). SetFileShortName does not effect this. So How to flush changes made by SetFileShortName?

Comment: What does `SetFileShortNameW` return?

Comment: You are still doing the error checking incorrectly. Why do you ever call `SetLastError`? Stop doing that. Do what the docs say and check the return value of functions before calling `GetLastError`. Only call `GetLastError` when the docs say it has meaning. In the case of `SetFileShortName` the docs could not be more clear: *If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.*

Comment: I guess I made a mistake here. innocent mistake that was... :) I have edited my code. Now SetFileShortName sets 1314 as error which means I still dont have required privilege. But I check privileges of my process at run time using process explorer, which shows SE_RESTORE_NAME as enabled after ModifyPrivilege() method.

Comment: Now, if after you fix the error checking, you find that the call fails with `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD` then you've got a problem with the priv code. We cannot see that code.

Comment: I also wonder why you call `ModifyPrivilege(SE_RESTORE_NAME, FALSE);` at the end? What if the process already had the priv? You've now removed it.

Comment: For experimentation, I am using same code for ModifyPrivilege() as given on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387705(v=vs.85).aspx and it works by enabling process's SE_RESTORE_NAME privilege. I check it in process explorer.

Comment: Are you elevating your process?

Comment: I am running it as an administrator. God! I have missed such important details in my question.

Comment: I'd still like you to fix the error handling in the code in your question. But I think I'm clearer now on what you are doing. Thanks!

Comment: Are you checking errors in "ModifyPrivilege" ?

Comment: You are not collecting the error (if any) from ModifyPrivilege. See the usage of ModifyPrivilege on the link you have posted.

Comment: No but I check processes privileges through process explorer by setting up a break point before and after ModifyPrivilege(). Before ModifyPrivilege(), required privilege is disabled and after ModifyPrivilege(), privilege is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the privilege **before** you call `CreateFile`.

---

Your error handling is a bit messed up too. There's no need for any calls to `SetLastError`. You simply need to check the return values of the API call before you call `GetLastError`. Only call `GetLastError` if the docs say that it has meaning. In the case of `SetFileShortName`, as is the case for many API calls, you only call `GetLastError` when the API call returns `FALSE`. So you should write:

```
if (!SetFileShortNameW(hFile, L""))
{
    error = GetLastError();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. :) and thanks for advice. Appreciated.